# Is there a set date for Sword Art Online Ordinal Scale to be released on DVD?

Tags: sword-art-online, merchandise

I've looked around but can't seem to find one. Does anyone know when the dvd will be released in the US?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about an international release, but the movie will be released in Japan on September 26th or 27th, 2017. CDJapan has both the Japanese [DVD](http://www.cdjapan.co.jp/product/ANSB-14001) and [Blu-ray](http://www.cdjapan.co.jp/product/ANSX-14001) versions available for pre-order now. The Japanese copies have been confirmed to have English subtitles.

[Japanese source on AnimeAnime.jp](https://animeanime.jp/article/2017/06/30/34460.html)

[English site using the AnimeAnime.jp site as a source](https://otakumode.com/news/59560184a5f8449412d3ce48/Sword-Art-Online-Ordinal-Scale-Blu-ray-DVD-On-Sale-Sept-27!)

Answer (score 0):

[Aniplex of America has announced Ordinal Scale for December 19th.](http://www.crunchyroll.com/anime-news/2017/08/11-1/aniplex-of-america-outlines-plans-for-anohana-monogatari-and-sword-art-online-blu-rays) (The details are roughly halfway down the page.)